# master struct pointing to other structs- how to use the values outside of main

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct

So I have 3 files:

1. .h file: have my structs, a, b, & c,  stored here
2. .cpp file: contains some functions I have written
3. .cpp main file: contains my main

In my .h file, I have multiple structs, lets say:

```
    struct a{
..many fields of different types.....
};

struct b{
...many different fields of different types...
};

struct c{
.......many different fields of different types
};
```

Now, I want to create another struct, that holds pointers to these structs, lets say:

```
struct master{
  a *first;
  b *second;
  c *third;
};
```

In my cpp file where I write my functions I need everything to be "declared" so that I can use all the fields of a, b, and c in my functions before getting to main. The purpose of this is that as I write functions I'm needing to pass too many parameters (there's over 20 fields of some structs)that's just making everything cluttered.

So where would my master struct go? How can everything be declared in such a way that I can use, lets say the value "x" from struct a when writing functions? How do I declare struct a, b, and c so that master struct recognizes them as the exact a, b, and c it points to?

These obviously aren't the actual structs from my problem. I tried to give a simple example so any questions are welcome. The master struct is vital to my program design. I'm writing in C++

EDIT EDIT:
structures.h:

```
struct a{
  int x;
  int w;
};

struct b{
  int y;
  int z;
};

struct master{  //if this should even go in .h?
  a *first;
  b * second;
};
```

functions.cc:

master myMaster;

```
 int add(int y){
      int myValue = y + m.second->x;
      return myValue;
    }
```

main.cc:

```
 int main (void) {
    extern master myMaster;
    a myA;
    myMaster.first = &myA;
    myMaster.first->x  = 10;
    int y = 3;
    int myValue = add(y);
  }
```

Comment: You'd pass a `struct master` argument with some name (say `m`) and use `m.first->x`? Or pass a `struct master *` and use `m->first->x`? (This should be obvious already; I'm sure there's something about your question I haven't understood correctly)

Comment: I understand how to use the pointers after.. but its saying that the values are undeclared when I try to use them in functions even when including .h

Comment: Let me rephrase in the standard format: 1) What exactly did you do? 2) What were you expecting to happen? and 3) What happened instead?

Comment: I will edit to add an exact example.

Comment: Are you using your master struct as a function parameter, or as a global variable?  It appears to be the latter.

Comment: See example I just added. I think as a global variable but only so that I can use values of the structs it points to as parameters

Comment: @immibis I shouldn't have said undeclared, I just mean the compiler is not recognizing it since I am using part of these structs before I formally declare them in main. The exact error is; expected unqualified-expression before '.' token master.second->x. So obviously it needs declared somewhere before use.

Comment: Do you know what a struct is? A struct is not a group of variables. A struct is like a "blueprint" for a group of variables. There is no such thing as `master.second` - however, if you actually declare a variable of type `master` (say with `master m;`) then there is such a thing as `m.second`.

Comment: I do know what a struct is. I guess I'm not wording this for your satisfaction. So are you saying that struct a {int x; int y;} isn't valid? Because it is. And okay. I added the declaration master m; still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm saying that `struct a {int x; int y;};` doesn't declare a variable called `a.x` or a variable called `a.y`. Does `int main (void) {int y = 3; a.x = 10; int myValue = add(y);}` work for you? Because it doesn't.

Comment: I do know what a struct is. I don't know how to use fields from structs in writing functions before having to make a struct declaration in main. I know it is possible because I have seen code that does it. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this myself, that is why I have posted on this forum. Please see the original question.

Comment: When you declared `m`, did you also define all of its members?

Comment: like structs first & second? I just did and still, it does not seem to want to let me use any members in the functions.cc - i edited functions.cc this is the only way i can compile without errors. but I get a segmentation fault so somethings wrong here

Comment: @minusila  Can you edit your question and add to it some of the code that you are actually using?

Comment: I have wrote the program in a different way and I have to rewrite my whole program because I move further along I am passing 8+ parameters. I have not yet written the full code, which will take a long time to do. I just want to feel this idea out before I take the time to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be entirely misunderstanding how structs work.

```
int main (void) {
  int y = 3;
  master.first->x = 10;
  int myValue = add(y);
}
```

`master.first` is not a thing that exists in the program at runtime - it's only used by the compiler.

You need to create *an instance of* the struct. I'll call it `myMaster`. You should change that to a better name.

```
int main (void) {
  int y = 3;
  master myMaster;
  myMaster.first->x = 10;
  int myValue = add(y);
}
```

This will compile. It will still *probably* crash because `myMaster.first` is now an uninitialized pointer - it doesn't actually point to an `a`.

```
int main (void) {
  int y = 3;
  master myMaster;
  a myA;
  myMaster.first = &myA;
  myMaster.first->x = 10;
  int myValue = add(y);
}
```

Now `myMaster.first` points to `myA`. The line `myMaster.first->x = 10;` is equivalent to `myA.x = 10;`

(Note that if `myMaster.first` was actually an `a`, not just a pointer to an `a`, then `myMaster.first.x = 10;` would be just fine without having to create a separate `a`)

So how do you pass it to a function? Just like any other parameter. I'll choose a silly name to remind you to change it.

```
// in main
int myValue = add(y, myMaster);

// other file
int add(int y, master blurrgh)
{
  int myValue = y + blurrgh.second->x;
  return myValue;
}
```

Like any parameter (including `y`), `add` will get a copy of `myMaster` this way, which you can use. Also like any parameter, if you don't want `myMaster` to be copied, then you can pass a pointer to it instead.

Comment: okay great this worked. Another thing I did (which seems to be working but my real program is more complicated) is declared my master in functions.cc. And then in main I "declared" it again using `extern master myMaster;`. And then I didn't have to feed master as a parameter. Is this a proper use of extern or am I missing something

Comment: @minusila That is how you can create a global variable, yes. But if you're going to do that why not just have `first` and `second` be global variables?

Comment: I see what you mean. I have about 6 structs I need to store in master struct for the real program and there's also going to be other members within that I create. It's a program for a class and my professor recommended doing it this way. Maybe to make sure everything is in one struct, i'm not 100%